# SQL get last 90 days records of an id, with each id having different last day

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a "Daily usage" table that goes like this:

```
ID, Date, Usage
1, 2018-07-25, 30
1, 2018-07-23, 30
1, 2018-07-22, 30
1, 2018-07-21, 30
1, 2018-07-20, 30
2, 2018-07-29, 30
2, 2018-07-28, 30
2, 2018-07-27, 30
2, 2018-07-26, 30
```

How to get last 3 days records of an id, with each id having different last day, preferably in Netezza SQL, ie

```
ID, Date, Usage
1, 2018-07-25, 30
1, 2018-07-23, 30
2, 2018-07-29, 30
2, 2018-07-28, 30
2, 2018-07-27, 30
```

Note that for ID=1, only get 07-25 (day 3) and 07-23 (day 1), but not 07-22, as I want any available date in the range of 3 days from the last day

I think rank() or row_number() probably won't fit the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

EDIT:

If you want up to 2 days before the maximum, then use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= duration_subtract(max_date, -2);
```

Comment: Hey I have edited my question above. this helps a bit tho, given that we have consecutive days of usage most of the time.

Comment: The max date solution is so simple yet so hard for me to come out with! Thanks!